# How to emit event in a Turbo Module on iOS

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, react-native, react-native-turbomodule

I'm following the guide here to create a Turbo Module in React Native.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-turbomodules

How do you emit events on iOS? The documentation only shows how to call a native function from React, but not how to emit an event from the Turbo Module.

For Android, you get a `ReactApplicationContext` object, which lets you create an emitter like this using the context object.

```
private val emitter = context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
emitter.emit(eventName, eventArray)
```

How do you do the same thing on iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To emit events to RN from iOS you should make your own emitter class that is inherited from `RCTEventEmitter` and then init it on JS side with `NativeEventEmitter` and add listeners for needed events with `addListener`:

**EventEmitter.h**

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface EventEmitter : RCTEventEmitter

+ (instancetype)shared;

@end
```

**EventEmitter.m**

```objectivec
#import "EventEmitter.h"

// Events
static NSString* onMyEvent = @"onMyEvent";

// Variable to save the instance
static EventEmitter* eventEmitter = nil;

@implementation EventEmitter

/// Exposing "EventEmitter" name to RN
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(EventEmitter);

// Called from RN
- (instancetype)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    eventEmitter = self;
  }
  return self;
}

+ (BOOL)requiresMainQueueSetup {
    return NO;
}

+ (instancetype)shared {
  return eventEmitter;
}

// List of supported events
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[onMyEvent];
}

@end
```

How to call:

```objectivec
NSDictionary* body = @{@"message" : @"Hello Emitter!"};
[EventEmitter.shared sendEventWithName:@"onMyEvent" body:body];
```

**RN/JS**

```js
import {
  ...
  NativeEventEmitter,
  NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';
import type EmitterSubscription from 'react-native';

class EventHandler extends React.Component {
  eventsSubscription: EmitterSubscription;

  componentDidMount() {
    const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.EventEmitter);

    this.eventsSubscription = eventEmitter.addListener('onMyEvent', event => {
      console.log(event.message); // Prints "Hello Emitter!"
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.eventsSubscription.remove();
  }

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks! The only other thing I add to do was `[self addListener:@"onMyEvent"]` in my RCTEventEmitter inherited class class.